# Create pyramid chart image with partial levels filled out

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, reporting

I need to be able to generate a colorful image (jpg, gif, etc..) for reporting purposes for use in a website.  It needs to be presented in the visual form of a pyramid.  There are multiple levels of data being collected where each level represents 0-X, where I'm trying to represent a progress completed at a specific level.

Example..

Level 1 = (1 of 1 completed) <-- Top of pyramid

Level 2 = (2 of 2 Completed)

Level 3 = (1 of 3 completed)

Level 4 = (2 of 4 completed) <-- Bottom of pyramid

I don't have enough reputation points yet to post an image, so I hope my description is sufficient to visualize what I'm trying to represent.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Or is there already a solution within .net (or 3rd party), for this type of solution?

Answer (score 0):

Chart Control that's build in .NET has a Pyramid chart as one of the chart types - read on [MS Charts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456753%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for additional information and how to get started.

One of your tags mentions"Reporting". [Microsofts SSRS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220409.aspx) also has a Pyramid chart type.

If you're interested in commercial 3rd party solutions, [Fusion Charts](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/flex/charts/Contents/ChartSS/PyramidXML.html) is one of the examples with plenty of bells and whistles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I'll look into these this afternoon.  At first glance I'm wondering if these are just the standard pyramid charts.  I'm going to look through them to see if they provide a way to have progress levels per each level of the pyramid.  Thanks again for providing a direction to look into.

Comment: They can display whatever you want them to display - that would depend on the data you feed them